# Creating a new dataframe colum as a function of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `Country` column. It has rows for around 15 countries.  I want to add a `Continent` column using a mapping dictionary, `ContinentDict`, that has mapping from country name to Continent name)

I see that these two work

1. `df['Population'] = df['Energy Supply'] / df['Energy Supply per Capita']`
2. `df['Continent'] = df.apply(lambda x: ContinentDict[x['Country']], axis='columns')`

but this does not

3. `df['Continent'] = ContinentDict[df['Country']]`

Looks like the issue is that `df['Country']` is a series object and so the statement is not smart enough to treat the last statement to be same as 2.

Questions

1. Would love to understand why statement 1 works but not 3.  Is it because "dividing two series objects" is defined as an element wise divide?
2. Any way to change 3 to tell I want element wise operation without having to go the `apply` route?

Comment: If you really want to have an answer question 1, you should rephrase your post only focus on it. If you only care about answering question 2, find the answer in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your statement **a mapping dictionary, `ContinentDict`**, it looks like `ContinentDict` is a Python dictionary. In this case,

```
ContinentDict[some_key]
```

is a pure Python call, regardless of what object `some_key` is. That's why the 3rd call fails since the `df['Country']` is not in the dictionary key (and it never can be since dictionary keys are not mutable).

In which case, Python only allows to index the exact key and throws an error when the key is not in the dictionary.

Pandas does provide a tool for you to replace/map the values:

```
df['Continent'] = df['Country'].map(ContinentDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Continent']=df['Country'].map(ContinentDict)
```

- In case 1, you are dealing with two pandas series, so it knows how to deal with them.
- In case 2, you have a python dictionary and pandas series, pandas don't know how to deal with a dictionary(df['country'] is pandas series but not a key in the dictionary)